# Получение параметров аудиоустройства через WinAPI

Tags: windows, аудио

Где в реестре хранится режим по умолчанию для такого же аудиоустройства?
Можно ли его считать через WinAPI?

[image: Что надо вытащить]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат вывода звука по умолчанию хранится в ключе реестра

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{GUID устройства}\Properties

Значение `{f19f064d-082c-4e27-bc73-6882a1bb8e4c},0` формата REG_BINARY хранит структуру WAVEFORMATEX или WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE (в зависимости от крутости устройства).

Для считывания можно использовать *[Multimedia Device API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370794(v=vs.85).aspx)*. Интерфейс `IPropertyStore` от объекта `IMMDevice` имеет свойство `PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat` (blob, содержащий одну из вышеуказанных структур). Пример кода для вывода имени, ID и сведений об аудиоформате активных устройств:

```
#define INITGUID
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <Shobjidl.h>
#include <MMDeviceAPI.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h>

//Используемые библиотеки: winmm.lib;strmiids.lib;quartz.lib;uuid.lib

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    TCHAR* pstr=NULL;
    DWORD state;

    IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDeviceCollection *deviceCollection = NULL;
    IMMDevice* dev=NULL;
    IPropertyStore *propertyStore=NULL;
    WAVEFORMATEX wex;//буфер для данных о формате

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&deviceEnumerator));
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("CoCreateInstance fail: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto End;}


    hr = deviceEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender,  DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, &deviceCollection);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("EnumAudioEndpoints fail: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto End;}

    UINT deviceCount;
    hr = deviceCollection->GetCount(&deviceCount);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetCount fail: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto End;}

    //display all endpoints
    for (UINT DeviceIndex = 0 ; DeviceIndex < deviceCount; DeviceIndex++)
    {
        deviceCollection->Item(DeviceIndex,&dev);
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Item fail: 0x%x\n",hr);goto Next;}

        dev->GetId(&pstr);
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Can't get device ID: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto Next;}

        hr = dev->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &propertyStore);     
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Can't open property store: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto Next;}

        PROPVARIANT friendlyName;
        PropVariantInit(&friendlyName);

        hr = propertyStore->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &friendlyName);      
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Can't get device name: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto Next;}

        printf("\n");
        wprintf(friendlyName.pwszVal); 
        printf("\n");
        PropVariantClear(&friendlyName);

        printf("Device id: ");
        wprintf(pstr);
        printf("\n");       

        dev->GetState(&state);
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Can't get state: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto Next;}
        printf("State: %d\n",state);

        PROPVARIANT format;
        PropVariantInit(&format);

        hr = propertyStore->GetValue(PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat, &format);
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Can't get format: HRESULT 0x%x",hr);goto Next;}

        printf("\n* Audio Format: *\n");        
        memcpy_s(&wex,sizeof(wex),format.blob.pBlobData,sizeof(wex));//копировать данные формата в буфер
        printf("Format tag: 0x%x\n",(int)wex.wFormatTag);
        printf("Channels: %d\n",(int)wex.nChannels);
        printf("Bits per sample: %d\n",(int)wex.wBitsPerSample);
        printf("Frequency: %d\n",(int)wex.nSamplesPerSec);
        printf("Block align: %d\n",(int)wex.nBlockAlign);
        PropVariantClear(&format);

        /* ****************** */

Next:   if(dev!=NULL){dev->Release();dev=NULL;}
        if(propertyStore!=NULL){propertyStore->Release();propertyStore=NULL;}

    }//end for


End:if(dev!=NULL){dev->Release();dev=NULL;}
    if(propertyStore!=NULL){propertyStore->Release();propertyStore=NULL;}
    if(deviceEnumerator!=NULL){deviceEnumerator->Release();deviceEnumerator=NULL;}
    if(deviceCollection!=NULL){deviceCollection->Release();deviceCollection=NULL;}  

    CoUninitialize();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Результат:**

[image: Форматы аудио]