# Получить свойства звукового устройства с помощью MMDevice API

Tags: c++, c, аудио, mmdevice

Требуется получить определённые свойства звукового устройства(выделю на скриншоте). Я дошёл до свойств, получил количество этих свойств, могу к ним обратиться - но что делать далее не знаю. Подскажите, как получить данные свойства(именно, наименование, количество..)
Код:

```
    HRESULT hresult; // для ошибок и проверок
    const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
    const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
    CoInitialize(NULL); // инициализируем систему COM
    hresult = CoCreateInstance( // создаем COM - объект, связанный с устройствами аудио вывода
        CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        (void**)&enumerator);

    IMMDeviceCollection *pCollection = nullptr; // указатель на коллекцию устройств
    IMMDevice *pEndpoint = NULL; // указатель на конкретное устройство

    hresult = this->enumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints( // получаем список устройств в системе(оно одно у меня, добавлять не думаю, но
        // если буду - делать проверку устройств(ниже) в цикле, там надо получить количество устройств ещё
        eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE,
        &pCollection);

    hresult = pCollection->Item(0, &pEndpoint); // получаем единственное устройство в системе
    IPropertyStore* propertys; // свойства устройства
    hresult = pEndpoint->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &propertys); // получаем свойства устройства для чтения(запись нам не нужна)
    DWORD count;  propertys->GetCount(&count);
    for (DWORD i(0); i < count; i++)
    {
        PROPERTYKEY prop;
        propertys->GetAt(i, &prop);
        // конкретные свойства(какие?) лежат в prop, но как "расшифровать" - не понимаю
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанные вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708024/Получение-параметров-аудиоустройства-через-winapi/727144#727144 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668189/Отобразить-подключенное-звуковое-устройство/724444#724444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения GUID свойств находятся в *Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h*. Например, имя устройства - `PKEY_Device_FriendlyName`.

Но информация о разъемах - это не свойства. Ее получают с помощью другого API -  [Device Topology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370825(v=vs.85).aspx). Интерфейс `IKsJackDescription` позволяет получить структуру `KSJACK_DESCRIPTION`, содержащую данные о типе разъема, его расположении и т.д.

Пример кода для вывода ID, имени и информации о разъемах для всех аудиоустройств:

```
#define INITGUID
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <Shobjidl.h>
#include <MMDeviceAPI.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h>
#include <Devicetopology.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib")


#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
              if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
 CoInitialize(NULL);
 TCHAR* pstr=NULL;
 DWORD state;

 IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
 IMMDeviceCollection *deviceCollection = NULL;
 IMMDevice* dev=NULL;
 IPropertyStore *propertyStore=NULL;
 IDeviceTopology *pDeviceTopology = NULL;
 IConnector *pConnFrom = NULL;
 IConnector *pConnTo = NULL;
 IPart *pPart = NULL;
 IKsJackDescription *pJackDesc = NULL;

 HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&deviceEnumerator));
 if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("CoCreateInstance failed");goto End;}

 /*Получение аудиоустройств*/ 
 hr = deviceEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender,  DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE|DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED, &deviceCollection);
 if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("EnumAudioEndpoints failed");goto End;}

 UINT deviceCount;
 hr = deviceCollection->GetCount(&deviceCount);
 if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetCount failed");goto End;}

 for (UINT DeviceIndex = 0 ; DeviceIndex < deviceCount; DeviceIndex++)
 {
    deviceCollection->Item(DeviceIndex,&dev);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Item failed");continue;}
    dev->GetId(&pstr);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetId failed");continue;}
    printf("Device id: ");
    wprintf(pstr);
    printf("\n");


    hr = dev->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &propertyStore); 
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("OpenPropertyStore failed");goto Next;}

    /*Получение имени устройства*/
    PROPVARIANT friendlyName;
    PropVariantInit(&friendlyName);
    hr = propertyStore->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &friendlyName);

    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetValue failed");goto Next;}
    wprintf(friendlyName.pwszVal);
    printf("\n");
    PropVariantClear(&friendlyName);  

    /*Получение информации о разъемах*/

    hr = dev->Activate(__uuidof(IDeviceTopology), CLSCTX_ALL,
                           NULL, (void**)&pDeviceTopology);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("Activate failed");goto Next;}

    hr = pDeviceTopology->GetConnector(0, &pConnFrom);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetConnector failed");goto Next;} 

    hr = pConnFrom->GetConnectedTo(&pConnTo);
    if (HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) == hr)
    {
        // The adapter device is not currently active.
        hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetConnector 2 failed");goto Next;} 

    // Get the connector's IPart interface.
    hr = pConnTo->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IPart), (void**)&pPart);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("QueryInterface failed");goto Next;}

    // Activate the connector's IKsJackDescription interface.  
    hr = pPart->Activate(CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                         __uuidof(IKsJackDescription), (void**)&pJackDesc);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("IKsJackDescription failed: %d\n",hr);goto Next;}

    UINT jacks=0;
    KSJACK_DESCRIPTION jdesc;
    hr=pJackDesc->GetJackCount(&jacks);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetJackCount failed");goto Next;}
    printf("Jack count: %d\n\n",jacks);

    /*Вывод разъемов*/
    for(UINT i=0;i<jacks;i++){
        hr=pJackDesc->GetJackDescription(i,&jdesc);
        if(FAILED(hr)) {printf("GetJackDescription failed");continue;}
        printf("* Jack #%d *\n",(int)(i+1)); 

        if(jdesc.IsConnected==0){//состояние
            printf("Device not connected\n");      
        }else{
            printf("Device connected\n");
        }

        wprintf(L"Connection Type: ");
        switch (jdesc.ConnectionType)//тип разъема
        {
        case eConnType3Point5mm: wprintf(L"Разъем 3.5 мм \n");break;
        case eConnTypeAtapiInternal:wprintf(L"Разъем ATAPI \n");break;
        case eConnTypeRCA: wprintf(L"Разъем RCA \n");break;
        case eConnTypeQuarter: wprintf(L"Разъем 1/2 дюйма \n");break;
        case eConnTypeOtherAnalog: wprintf(L"Аналоговый разъем \n");break;
        case eConnTypeOtherDigital: wprintf(L"Цифровой разъем \n"); break;
        default: wprintf(L"0x%x\n",jdesc.ConnectionType); break;
        }

        wprintf(L"GeoLocation: ");

        switch (jdesc.GeoLocation)//расположение разъема
        {
        case eGeoLocFront: wprintf(L"Передняя панель\n");break;
        case eGeoLocRear: wprintf(L"Задняя панель\n");break;
        case eGeoLocHDMI: wprintf(L"HDMI\n");break;
        case eGeoLocATAPI: wprintf(L"ATAPI\n");break;
        case eGeoLocNotApplicable: wprintf(L"Не определено\n");break;
        default: printf("0x%x\n",jdesc.GeoLocation);break;
        }


     }
     /* очистка ресурсов */
  Next:SAFE_RELEASE(dev);SAFE_RELEASE(propertyStore);SAFE_RELEASE(pDeviceTopology);
       SAFE_RELEASE(pConnFrom);SAFE_RELEASE(pConnTo);SAFE_RELEASE(pPart);
       SAFE_RELEASE(pJackDesc);
       printf("\n");
 } 

End:
 SAFE_RELEASE(deviceEnumerator);
 SAFE_RELEASE(deviceCollection);
 system("PAUSE");
 CoUninitialize();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Астрономическое Вам спасибо! Вы очень выручили!
А что можно почитать на эту тему, кроме MSDN?

Comment: @Range Какой-то специальной литературы по данным API нет, тем более на русском, так как это вещи довольно узкой направленности, и официальная документация достаточно подробна. Теорию можно почитать здесь: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/09/23/new-audio-apis-for-vista/ Примеры кода можно искать на en so на пересечении меток windows и audio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio+windows Там в том числе и сами сотрудники Microsoft отвечают, так что это один из лучших источников информации.

Comment: И вновь большое Вам спасибо.